# Compare Two arrays in PowerShell Not working

Tags: arrays, powershell, powercli

I have two arrays, on as a result of loading a txt file with vSphere VMNames and the other as a result of a PowerCli query:

```
$WindowsVMsVsphere = Get-VMguest * | Where-Object {$_.OSFullName -like "*Windows*" } | Select-Object vmName

$WindowsVMsExcel = Get-Content -Path C:\temp\vms.txt
```

When I compare both arrays (to match same name Vms) I get the following result (this is just an extract):

```
@{VmName=VMNAME1}                             =>
VMNAME1                                       <=
```

Clearly the problem is that I amnot comparing the same values, I am comparing sub-arrays inside one array with values from another array.

I am pretty new to advanced PowerShell, can anybody give me some hints?.

Thanks!

Comment: try`select-object -expandproperty vmName` instead of `select-object vmName`

Comment: Same result, Sadly.

Comment: If @guiwhatsthat hint doesn't work you presumably did something wrong. An alternative way to expand is `$WindowsVMsVsphere = (Get-VMguest * | Where-Object {$_.OSFullName -like "*Windows*" }).vmName`

Comment: Also, what does your file `C:\temp\vms.txt` look like. Is that simply a list of VM names, each on a separate line or is there more to take into account?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show a [mcve] of your code (including the actual comparison) as well as a sample input file.